# Mongoose migrating a collection to a new collection in real time using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, migration, production

I am migrating a service between a Java server (Server A) to a NodeJs server (Server B), in real time at PRODUCTION env.
As part of the migration - I transfer data (4 million documents) stored in MongoDB
from an "OldCollection" to a "NewCollection".
There is a script which reads data from the "OldCollection" in batches, and transforms the data to the "NewCollection".

The script example is as follows :

```
const oldCollectionLength = await mongoClient.connection
    .collection('myOldCollection')
    .countDocuments();

const skip = 0;
const limit = 1000;

 while (skip < oldCollectionLength) {
    const oldDocumentsBatch = (await mongoClient.connection
      .collection('myOldCollection')
      .find({}, { skip, limit })
      .toArray()) as unknown as OldCollectionModel[];

    const bulk = [];

    for (const oldDocument of oldDocumentsBatch) {
      try {
        const newDocument = toNewDocument(oldDocument);
        bulk.push(newDocument);
      } catch (error) {
        // some error handling
      }
    }
    await MyNewModel.insertMany(bulk); // adding multiple documents to the new model
    skip += limit;
  }
```

This script took 20 minutes to finish.

The issue occurs, when in real time while the script is running, new documents are inserted to the "OldCollection".

Suppose the total documents length is exactly 4 million.
When the script was running for those 4 million documents, 3000 new documents were inserted to the "OldCollection".
So, while reading the documents in batches using skip and limit, I was having an 11000 error code - duplication mongo error.
It happened since the order of the documents isn't kept, which lead me into reading and inserting the same document twice.

I thought about storing update operations in an array and use `BulkWrite` with `upsert:true` , but still the script might loose documents from these previous 4million old documents, since the order is changed, which affects the read in batches.

Are there any better solution of reading the 4 million documents, and ensure the 4 million documents which the script intended to migrate, will be migrated even if new 3000 are inserted while the script is running ?

The Code takes care of the new 3000 documents at a different handler, so the solution  for the script shouldn't include handling new documents created after the migration started.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How complicated is `toNewDocument`?  I'm wondering if a single aggregation pipeline with `"$out"` at the end might perform well to do the entire migration.

Comment: pretty complicated - there is an async operation inside it, and some data manipulation.

Comment: however, I can use the $out aggregation to copy the same old collection to another collection, and then run the migration on that copy, and It ensures the copied data wont change